# How to resize, optimize multiple pictures in laravel job before saving and without using third party service?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

Is there a way to optimized and resized upload pictures in Laravel before even saving the picture to server-side and without using third party service if you deal with multiple image upload?. I was passing request object to the dispatch method:

```php
    ProcessUploadedImage::dispatch($request);
```

According to Laravel documentation, it is not allowed to pass serialized object to Laravel job.

Comment: You could do it in JavaScript (using canvas) before the file is uploaded at all. Then the upload size will be smaller and will be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Aftet user sent you a request with an image in it, its saved locally in a tmp directory. so it saved anyway.

I suggest you to use spatie medialibrary for your project to manipulate images in jobs such as resize or opimize or even convert